# Как поставить ограничение на данный позицию X?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код

```
$(document.body).on("mousemove", function(event) {
      if ($dragging) {
          var left = $('#panor-move').css('left')
          left = parseFloat(left)
          $dragging.offset({
              left: event.pageX
          });

      }
  });


  $(document.body).on("mousedown", "#panor-move", function (event) {
      $dragging = $(event.target);
  });

  $(document.body).on("mouseup", function (event) {
      $dragging = null;
  });
```

Который двигает по оси X. Можно ли сделать что бы left был максимальным 370 а минимальным 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы ограничить положение, достаточно добавить соответствующие проверки, перед вызовом `$dragging.offset({`, например:

```
if ($dragging) {
    var left = $('#panor-move').css('left');
    left = parseFloat(left);
    if(left < 10) left = 10; // если передвинули левее, устанавливаем в крайнюю левую точку
    if(left > 370) left = 370; // если передвинули правее, устанавливаем в крайнюю правую точку
    $dragging.offset({
        left: event.pageX
    });
}
```